# Error: connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com #0 - LARAVEL

Tags: laravel, xampp

I am trying send emails but I am getting the error below:

> "connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com #0".

I made test with different ports (465, 578), with SSL and TLS and the last with the mail account and it is working.

I think that the problem is on XAMPP.

What am I doing wrong and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Show you mail configuration in your .env file

Comment: MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxxxxx@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30627343/7809177)

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

> MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
>
> MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
>
> MAIL_PORT=587
>
> MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
>
> MAIL_USERNAME=y*****4@gmail.com
>
> MAIL_PASSWORD=a*****

Hope, it works for you.